# Supplication (dua) for sakina

Tags: dua

There is usually a supplication from an authentic source (such as the major hadith collections) for (almost) every occasion. Is there one for: asking for sakina (tranquility)?

Comment: I need to ask whether you look for one du'a covering both or some du'a for each of them. In the later case consider splitting the question. As there are plenty falling under (1).

Comment: Okay. I'll split the question in due course.